# Octal values -- in JDK8?

Tags: java, java-8, literals, octal

This Q is for verification.

JDK 8 seems to be processing octal when the literal value is preceeded with a 0:

```
  System.out.print(011);
```

printing 9, and

```
  System.out.print(08);
```

giving a checked error.

This isn't in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)-- yet(?)

Is this new in jdk8? if so - are there some details in case of octal, additional to those in HEX and binary?

TIA

//=============================

EDIT:

The Q is about JDK processing octal-- since when. the dosc showing only HEX & binary.

that 2nd code line is there to show it's octal JDK doing when the value is preceeded by a 0.

Comment: 8 is not a valid octal value

Answer (score 9):

It's been in Java forever... the bit of the JLS you want is [section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

(It's in the [first edition of the JLS too](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/3.doc.html#48282).)

You shouldn't expect the Java tutorial to be complete on every aspect of the language - that would be overwhelming for the target audience. For aspects like this, the specification is the document to be looking at.